Deploying indexes to a specific firestore database
I have the following index in my firestore.indexes.json
  "indexes": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "programsForQuery",
      "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
      "fields": [
        { "fieldPath": "cipCode", "order": "ASCENDING" },
        { "fieldPath": "state", "order": "ASCENDING" },
        { "fieldPath": "sortOrder", "order": "DESCENDING" },
        { "fieldPath": "__name__", "order": "DESCENDING" }
      ]
    },
]

When I run firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes it deploys the indexes to my "default" firestore database, however, within my firestore project I have two different databases. The second database is called "national". I need these indexes deployed to the national database, not the default database in my firestore project.
I haven't been able to find documentation for how to do this, does anyone here know?

It looks like you will need to add a configuration to refer the named database to a file with the indexes you want for that database.  From the documentation:

If your project contains multiple Cloud Firestore databases, edit your
firebase.json file to associate different Cloud Firestore Security
Rules and database index source files with each database. Modify the
file with a JSON array, with one entry for each database.
      "firestore": [
        {
          "database": "(default)",
          "rules": "firestore.default.rules",
          "indexes": "firestore.default.indexes.json"
        },
        {
          "database": "ecommerce",
          "rules": "firestore.ecommerce.rules",
          "indexes": "firestore.ecommerce.indexes.json"
        }
      ], ```


